# Moose: How to get an array of objects? Traits?

Tags: perl, moose

I'm beginning to realize that this is for beginners:

```
package Bad;

has 'arr' => ( is => 'rw', 'ArrayRef[Str]' );

package main;

my $bad = Bad->new(arr => [ "foo", "bar" ]);
print $bad->arr->[0], "\n";
```

Enter traits. I'm underwhelmed by the traits API, though. Have I misunderstood something? Can I get this API instead somehow? :

```
print $bad->arr->get(0), "\n";
```

#### Details

Review the canonical traits example from [Moose::Meta::Attribute::Native::Trait::Array](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Moose/lib/Moose/Meta/Attribute/Native/Trait/Array.pm)

```
package Stuff;
use Moose;

has 'options' => (
    traits  => ['Array'],
    is      => 'ro',
    isa     => 'ArrayRef[Str]',
    default => sub { [] },
    handles => {
        all_options    => 'elements',
        add_option     => 'push',
        map_options    => 'map',
        filter_options => 'grep',
        find_option    => 'first',
        get_option     => 'get',
        join_options   => 'join',
        count_options  => 'count',
        has_options    => 'count',
        has_no_options => 'is_empty',
        sorted_options => 'sort',
    },
);

no Moose;
1;
```

An object declared like that is used e.g.:

```
my $option = $stuff->get_option(1);
```

I really don't like that for one array attribute I get and have to manually name 11 methods in my Stuff class - one for every single operation that one can do to 'options'. Inconsistent naming is bound to happen and it is bloaty.

How do I instead (elegantly) get an API like:

```
my $option = $stuff->options->get(1);
```

Where all the methods from [Moose::Meta::Attribute::Native::Trait::Array](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Moose/lib/Moose/Meta/Attribute/Native/Trait/Array.pm)  are implemented in a type-safe way?

Then all the operations on every single Array are named in exactly the same way...

(I'm actually using Mouse, but most of Mouse is identical to Moose)

Comment: You could use autobox, but AKHolland's answer is much better.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think that the best way to get your API into that format would be to create a new object for the options, and delegate the methods into it directly. Something like:

```
package Stuff;
use Moose;
use Stuff::Options;

has 'options' => (
    'is'      => "ro",
    'isa'     => "Stuff::Options",
    'default' => sub { Stuff::Options->new },
);

no Moose;
1;
```

And then in `Stuff/Options.pm`:

```
package Stuff::Options;
use Moose;

has '_options' => (
    'is'      => "ro",
    'isa'     => "ArrayRef[Str]",
    'traits'  => [ "Array" ],
    'default' => sub { [] },
    'handles' => [ qw(elements push map grep first get join count is_empty sort) ],
);

no Moose;
1;
```

This would allow code as in your example to work (`$stuff->options->get(1)`).

Comment: This definitely answers my question. Thanks!

In fact I think this is the *only* way I can create a hash-of-hashes which is why I've linked to this answer from another thread: [How to store Hash of Hashes in Moose?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28140469/345716).

It does get quite ugly if I need to initialize _options, though.

Comment: So now there's a need for Moose generics / templates. Because now I can see myself creating 99.5% boilerplate implementations of `Array_of_<class>` and `Hash_of_<class>` for many of the built-in data types and my own classes. E.g. the above `Stuff::Options` is really just `Array_of_Str`. (I'd be totally fine with `_options` being called something generic like `_array` above). How do I get `Array_of_Str` created automatically without having to write the 13 lines of boilerplate? (Isn't this exactly the reason that templates in C++ and generics in Java were invented?)

Comment: I don't know if this has changed, but I get error "The 'handles' option must be a HASH reference, not ARRAY(0x9c92a9c)" when trying this.

Comment: @UncleCarl what version of Moose do you have? This convention is still recommended in the current documentation http://search.cpan.org/dist/Moose/lib/Moose/Manual/Delegation.pod

Comment: @AKHolland, Moose version 2.2004. Thanks.

Comment: Seems to work fine for me in that version. Maybe you're doing something weird with roles? Would be a good question to post with more details.